# How to use custom alphanumeric sender id with Twilio Verify API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

How can I change the Sender name (alphanumeric sender id) for the OTP messages sent via the Twilio Verify API ? Currently the sender is shown as "AUTHY" for all messages, while I would like the company name instead.

The verify otp request api doesn't have a "from" parameter unlike the programmable sms api.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the sender ID. The AUTHY sender ID and associated numbers are whitelisted with carriers around the world to ensure that the messages get through and are not subject to carrier filtering.

Comment: I've tried Verify service in Nexmo. Nexmo allow to customize the Sender Id. It supports alpha numeric as well.